scatterplot with quadrants and fitted line for the whole sample
I read this website on how to create scatterplots with quadrants
How to create Quadrant Plots in R
This example is reproducible. If I add to the last part of the commands the  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x), that is
# Create a scatter plot with quadrant color-coding
ggplot(iris2, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color = quadrant)) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = x_mid) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = y_mid) +
    geom_point() +
    # Add labels to the plot based on the summary table 'iris_labels'
    geom_label(data = iris_labels,
               aes(label = paste0("n = ", n),
                   x = x, y = y, color = NULL,
                   hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust),
               fill = NA, label.size = 0,
               show.legend = FALSE) +
    labs(title = "Quadrant Plot of Iris Data",
         x = "Petal Length",
         y = "Petal Width")+
 stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x)

I get the fitted line in each quadrant.
I want to modify the above part of the code so as to get

exactly the same graph (with the same colors by quadrant, etc)
produced by the above code, plus the  fitted line  for the whole
sample.

the same graph produced by the above code with the same colors by
quadrant, etc but without the fitted line by quadrant; only the
fitted line for the whole sample.


Is there any way to do that?

How should we create iris2 and iris_labels?

First step, I'd take aes(color = quadrant) out of the global mapping and put it into any layers that specifically need it, like your geom_point, geom_label, and stat_smooth layers. (Currently, its appearance in global mapping tells ggplot2 that every layer should have groupings by quadrant, if applicable.) Then, you can add a stat smooth without that mapping that will fit the global data.

yes it worked! Thank you very much!
